# Which will wear longer, a single chainring with 11-speed cassette, or triple chainring with 8-speed cassette?

Tags: drivetrain

I am thinking of replacing the latter with the former. Someone said that the chain having to stretch 11 different ways would wear down the drive train faster. I think that the chain will last longer if it's not being thrown around at both ends. Who's right?

Comment: It depends on whether you ever shift gears or not.  The amount of "cross" in the chain is not that significant, especially given that either arrangement may have more "cross", depending on how one habitually rides.

Comment: Modern roller chains are engineered to get deflected sideways. Measurements of drivetrain efficiency typically cannot measure significant differences between straight and crossed chains. When friction losses are low wear is likely not much increased. There appears to be no reliable study on the effect of drivetrian wear. In any case, proper cleaning and lubrication has magnitudes higher influence on wear than any cross chaining or drivetrain layout.

Comment: What worry about wear. If its cost, go for 3x8 because being so 'last decade' no one wants it, its often heavily discounted.

Answer (score 5):

To all practical purposes, neither person is right.

Even if cross chaining wears out drive lines (highly debated), 1x11 cannot cross as much as 3x8. A correctly choose chain ring on a 1x11 means you will normally be in a mid rear cog, so in normal riding, very little cross chaining would occur. If you ride extremely hilly country, and often sit in very high or very low gears, then you will probably still have a similar chain angle to a 3x setup most of the time.

Chain wear and lifetime of drive chain comes down to a combination of regular maintenance, how much and in what way a bike is used. Within measurable parameters, a 1x11 will not wear out faster or slower than a 3x8. Over a large number of samples there might (although I have doubts) be a very small but statistically significant difference.

Why are you worried about wear. A 3x8 speed drive train is much cheaper than a 1x11, so replacement is cheaper.

There are valid reasons to go 1x11, and valid reasons not to, but wear is not one of them.

Comment: It sounds like the OP already owns a 1x11.  It will take a long time to offset the cost of purchasing the a new drivetrain, through the mall savings in maintenance.  I have been down that road when I costed out moving to 9 speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 3x front, odds are you will spend about half your time on the center ring and the other half split between the other two.  So you get roughly twice as much wear before front rings first need replacement.

If you have a 3x front and use it "normally", you will tend to use the larger front ring with smaller rear cogs, and vice-versa, reducing the amount of cross-chaining you'd have as compared to a single ring.

Having an 11x back will generally spread wear a bit more widely than an 8x back, meaning the 11x can go a little further than the 8x, on average.

Net-net is that it doesn't really matter.  What's important is which arrangement best fits your riding style.

Comment: Given that nearly all 8x cassettes are cheap, and all (?) 11x are expensive, spreading the wear over 11 sprockets might save you metal but not money. You're also likely to be in the middle of the range quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple different factors to consider. First of all, the 8 speed setup is going to use a chain with wider plates. This means that assuming both chains are of equal quality, the 8 speed chain will last longer because it's made of more material.

Another thing to look at is the amount of cross chaining. Cross chaining occurs when then two sprockets don't like up in a straight line between the front and the back, see the picture below. A 1x11 setup will in practice undergo more cross chaining than the 3x8 setup because there's only a single ring at the front that has to accommodate  all the rear gears. With the 3x8 setup, althought more extreme cross chaining is possible, in practice the rider shouldn't be using these extreme gears too often anyway. A 1x11 drive train is much more likely to be in a more extreme chain angle.

[image: Cross Chaining]

Comment: Does lateral displacement matter for chain wear and power transmission in modern chains? I don't have a deep insight on the matter yet, but the few papers I read seemed to suggest that power losses due to lateral displacement were insignificant in measurements of drive train losses. If no energy is lost to friction there oughtn't be increased wear either?

Comment: The cross chaining examples also lead to quite different chain tensions (when no torque is applied at the cogwheels). Bringing the derailleur to its extreme positions. Might that be contributing to wear/malfunctions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the focus is in the wrong place.

All your pedaling effort is transmitted via the chain, and causes wear on it, as well as on the various sprockets. The eight speed chain is much wider (7.1 mm) than the 11 speed chain (5.62 mm), hence the chain wears faster. (A simplistic argument, since there's more to it, but I've got to get out for a ride.)

The main reason road cyclists go for 10 or 11 speed chains and clusters is the weight. But even among cyclists who do regular maintenence, I see broken chains more frequently with these systems, and almost never with 8 speed systems.

Comment: I'm not sure that I buy that a wider chain wears more slowly because it has more material. Wear happens where the rollers contact the plates. Rollers are the same thickness regardless of chain width. I was unsure about plate width, but a quick Googling [indicates that it's the same](http://www.gizmology.net/sprockets.htm) as well. That being the case, they should wear at the same rate given the same type of use.

Comment: @andy256 are the cogs on the chainrings and cassette also wider? I know of narrower tolerances in 10/11 but haven't read of actual cog thickness.

Comment: At the same power output, chain speed tends to be higher on 1x systems since the front chainring tends to be larger. Since power transmission through the chain is proportional to chain speed * chain tension, at fixed power the chain tension tends to be lower. Wear on drivetrain components tends to be more closely related to chain tension than to chain speed since higher chain tension means higher force.

Comment: @R.Chung - But such an effect (if it exists at all) is minuscule.  Neither weight nor friction is a valid reason for choosing one scheme vs the other.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The difference in chain tension between a 50/25 at 90rpm and a 36/18 at 90rpm (same gear ratio, so same speed and same power) isn't minuscule -- it's 50/36, or 39%. The slower the chain moves at the same power, the higher the chain tension. The higher the chain tension, the more force exerted on drivetrain components. The more force exerted on drivetrain components, the greater the wear.

Comment: @jimirings I think the lateral flexing wears the narrow chain faster. I see people breaking 10 and 11 speed chains, and almost never see the wider chains break. Just last weekend, a client broke an 11 speed chain while riding with me. It broke while he was crossing the road, so it wasn't under much *tension* at the time.

Comment: @R.Chung - But the energy loss due to the chain in any reasonably well constructed setup is minuscule.  And a chain under higher tension (because of gear ratio differences) will move a shorter distance for the same total energy transmitted, so the wear balances out.  Plus, wear depends more on the quality of maintenance than on such details as chain tension.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Um, actually, no, drive train efficiency varies quite a bit with chain tension. See figure 3 at the bottom of page 6 [here](http://www.ihpva.org/HParchive/PDF/hp50-2000.pdf).  Chain speed depends on the size of the chain ring and the cadence, not on the rear cog. That's why chain speed on a 50/25 is faster than on a 36/18 at the same cadence even though they have the same gear ratio. And, yes, maintenance has a big effect but surely the question only makes sense when we hold maintenance constant.

Comment: @R.Chung that would be a good topic for a community wiki question. Something like "contributing factors to chain wear" perhaps? It would be a pity if it were hidden in some comments.

Comment: @andy256 would you describe how those chains failed? For example the reduced plate thickness is often mentioned as reducing chain reliability. However, do chains break at the plates? These surfaces ought not wear much during power transfer.

Comment: @gschenk In each case one of the outer plates was lost. Different chains same result. For the plate to come off the end of the pin has either worn away or the hole in the plate has worn.

Comment: @andy256 thank you! That is interesting. For the forces at this spot the plate thickness ought to be critical indeed.